# Want to add attributes to the options based on the option number, while using ng-options

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, ng-options

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <form name="myForm">
<label for="mySelect">Make a choice:</label>
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
  ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id"

custom-attribute = "{{optionNumber}}+ Value"

  ng-model="data.selectedOption"></select>
</form>
</div>

$scope.data = {
availableOptions: [
  {id: '1', name: 'Option A'},
  {id: '2', name: 'Option B'},
  {id: '3', name: 'Option C'}
]
```

In this example, I want to pass corresponding option number to the custom-attribute, based on the option number. For example: for option1 it will be "1 Value", for option2 it will be "2 Value".

Although, I can achieve it using ng-repeat instead of ng-options (with the help of $index). I want to do it using ng-options.

Comment: Your only options are to write your own ngOption like Directive or use ngRepeat on the <option> element.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the only way